# Require provision profile with apple pay feature xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath

Tags: flutter, xcodebuild

I am trying to export the ios(flutter) app using the manual command line as mentioned below. When I try to export ipa with this command it gives some profile-related error but when I checked the archive folder it contains the proper profile with the apple pay feature.

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/Runner.xcarchive -exportPath $PWD/build -exportOptionsPlist $PWD/config/ExportOptions.plist

Error:
error: exportArchive: "Dev.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Apple Pay feature.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 "Dev.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Apple Pay feature." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="Dev.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Apple Pay feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}